# Find ZIP Code from Latitude and Longitude

Tags: java, php, mysql, geolocation

I know there are web services out that have this information, however they can be limited to per day requests. I have about 114,000 records I need zip codes for. I have a data base full of zip codes with there lat and longs. However I am not sure how I can calculate the given lat and long against the zip code lat and long.

Basically I need to cross reference the given address lat and long against the supplied zip code lat and long. I can either use PHP, Java, or MySQL Procedure or just a calculation.

Comment: *"Basically I need to.."* ..ask a question.  Better still, make it a specific question.

Comment: Check this out... http://www.hashbangcode.com/comment/2732 - you can use Google but their terms of service state that you have to display a map!

Comment: I have been looking at http://www.geonames.org/ as the service. As mentioned there are limitations to their API calls which limit me to 2000 calls an hour. I have 114 thousand records I need ZIP codes for. Is is possible to calculate this from the given ZIP lat and longs?

Comment: Most postal services sell licences for this kind of data. If you're doing a lot of work with geolocation, addresses and zip codes it makes sense to purchase a licence. Some countries make this data available for free if it is used for a non-commercial project.

Comment: Use google geocoding interface and make the script limit its calls if need be.  Who cares if it takes a few days to get all the data you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a stepping stone but thats about it, in this case.

```
$distance = 10;
$latitude = 37.295092;
$longitude = -121.896490;

$sql = "SELECT loc.*, (((acos(sin(($latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((($longitude - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` FROM table_with_lonlat_ref loc HAVING distance < $distance"
```

if you create a query that does a JOIN between the 2 tables you have and reduce the distance to 1 or 2, you could in concept come up with just about all the lat/lon combinations you need. Or you could also find a DB that has all the US zipcodes, that also has lat/lon then query over one table to insert into another based on the matched zipcodes. I have such a zipcode DB somewhere.

also might I suggest http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite its never complete less you wanna pay for it and it changes up every so often but. From this you can get almost nearly every combination of lat/lon possible to use as your reference point based on IP of a visitor (its off a little in some cases as the IP may steam from a hub a town or 2 away. But its better than nothing, gives you only limits your server can handle, and no worry about API restrictions outside of usage terms from maxmind.

Anyway all in all, Ive been using this combination for a while on a number of sites and have yet to come up with much problems to date. Well I know its not a direct answer to your question but I hope it leads you to a solution

Comment: I have a data base already with zip code lat and longs. I was hoping to cross reference this. I will try the SQL code and see what happens. If all else fails I have the API service I an try. I was just hoping for something quicker. But I am sure after I figure out how to reference everything I could have already ran it through the API. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: no problem, if I wasn't at work right now I'd likely try to help you more indepth but, I can only procrastinate so long before getting in trouble.

Comment: It works well, not 100% accurate but it is must faster than running this through an API.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately almost all zipcode DB's the lat/lon points are associated with the center of the zipcode location. It's not down to the exact points. And by reducing the distance to 1 maybe 2 miles. Its a crap shoot as some calculations may fall short. Generally though better than nothing, and in the end will reduce you from 100k+ to maybe a couple thousand null entries that you can obtain through other slower means without waiting for days on end due to api limits, glad it worked to some extent for ya

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a database of lats and longs, I'm going to assume it describes a set of rectangular regions from (latA, lonA) to (latB, lonB), each with an associated zip code.  I'll also assume (or recommend) that you've indexed those four fields.

Your query can fairly easily match whether a coordinate (coordA, coordB) fits within the two ranges describing that rectangle.

```
update coords set zip_code=(
  select zip_code from zip_codes 
  where coords.coordA >= zip_codes.latA 
    and coords.coordA <= zip_codes.latB
    and coords.coordB >= zip_codes.lonA
    and coords.coordB <= zip_codes.lonB
    limit 1
)
```

Caviat:  You should verify whether latA < latB and lonA < lonB in your zip code database, and verify that you're using the same coordinate system in both tables.  You may need to make adjustments, either through a conversion or by changing the operators appropriately.